# JSF 2.0 implicit navigation, different views

Tags: view, navigation, jsf-2

I'm looking for a good explanation to JSF 2.0 implicit navigation and how it works with views. To be more precise, I understand that from an action method I can return a string which is the outcome of the action. If there's a JSF view whose file name matches the outcome, then this is implicit navigation.

Now... my question, what if the action is invoked from a view that's inside a folder but the view that I want to navigate to next is in a different folder?  I.e., from `/manager/edit.xhtml` an action is invoked. What String should that action return so that navigation can safely go to `/user/list.xhtml` or to `/index.xhtml` or to `/manager/index.xhtml`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge goes, JSF looks for a matching view only within the current context. You probably have to define a navigation rule in your faces-config.xml to handle an outcome in a special way. Here is an example:

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/profiles/viewkeypages.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>editkeypage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/users/editkeypage.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>      
</navigation-rule>
```

-Praveen.

Comment: Hello Praveen. 
Right, that's what I'm doing so far, I just wanted to verify this. I mean, it's just that the references I've read and the blogs I've encountered all mention the benefits of implicit navigation, but they **fall short of stating that it cannot replace navigation rules**, specifically because implicit navigation only works for views within the current context. Even in a small web application with a few views, we should organize these into directories thus creating contexts. **I want to confirm that to navigate to a different context requires the use of a navigation rule.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit navigation to get to views in other folders.

Just do something like this in a view:

```
<h:link value="Move" outcome="#{request.contextPath}/users/editkeypage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
```

or

```
<h:link value="Move" outcome="/users/editkeypage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
```

Comment: How is `faces-redirect=true` useful here on a plain GET link?

Comment: Well that part may not be needed, but you can go from a view in 1 folder to a view in another folder is what I was getting at. I just copy and pasted an example I had and forgot to remove that piece.