# Back button functionality in jsf2

Tags: jsf-2

Trying to navigate from page 1 to page 3 as well as page 2 to page3.In page3 when I click on back button it should navigate to the appropriate page.Could anyone please help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement url based navigation if you want to achieve that. To navigate from 1 to 3 you can implement an `<h:button>` with an outcome attribute.

`<h:button value="Go to third" outcome="/thirdpage.xhtml" />`

You can also do it specifying navigation rules. However you have dozens of tutorials to do this.

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-button-and-commandbutton-example/

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/

[JSF 2.0 implicit navigation, different views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545557/jsf-2-0-implicit-navigation-different-views)

In order to know where are you coming from there are different ways, but I think the right one is to use view params. In a button or link you can specify an `<f:param name="ComingFrom" value="#{sourceBean.id}" />` and you receive it in the destination page that way `<f:viewParam id="ComingFrom" name="ComingFrom"
                value="#{destinationBean._ParamSourceId}" />`.

That way you are passing parameters through the request and you can build your back button to point an url or the other one.

There you have more stuff.

https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_2_0_bookmarability_view

Comment: Thanks for your response.My question is in page 3 how to determine whether the request is coming from page 1 or page 2 so that the back button should navigate to the respective page.

Comment: I change my answer in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having a bean which has a field storing the previous page. Then in the third page you can use the value of this field to return to the appropriate page. For example in your first page you need to have a commandLink navigating you to third page, while setting the previousPage as firstPage. Similar commandLink should be part of second page too. You need to enclose h:commandLinks in h:forms as they use post method to pass parameters.

```
<h:commandLink value="Third  Page" action="#{navigationPageBean.updateLastVisitedPage("/firstPage.xhtml")}"/>

<h:commandLink value="Third  Page" action="#{navigationPageBean.updateLastVisitedPage("/secondPage.xhtml")}"/>

@Named
public class NavigationPageBean implements Serializable
{
    private String previousPage;

    public String updateLastVisitedPage(String pageName)
    {
        previousPage = pageName;
        return "/thirdpage.xhtml";
    }

    public String getPreviousPage()
    {
        return previousPage;
    }

    public void setPreviousPage(String previousPage)
    {
        this.previousPage = previousPage;
    }
}
```

You can achieve this by using javascript methods to learn the previous page too I think, but I don't know the exact methods.